# multiple datasheets reading in python 3.6

Tags: python, database, csv, xlrd

I'm trying to make a file that looks like excel with few sheets.
The goal is to be able to read from python 3.6 a specific sheet---> then to read specific column from this shit.

for example:

[image]

I want to read from python the dates sheet the time column.

If there is an option to do so with csv/any better file i would really like to hear or if there is a way to read like this from excel it would also work.

Thank you.

Comment: Please append the csv file and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: What is the question? If it is possible to read excel files using Python? Yes, it is possible, I do this very often.

Comment: the question is how to read specific sheet from excel xlsx because somewhy xlrd not working on my python 3.6. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) module if xlrd is not working (that is an interesting case). It is very simple to use. I didn't try but it should work on Python 3.6.

You can find some sample codes [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html).